# How to add a duplicate csv column using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a `CSV` that has just one column with `domains`, similar to this:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
cnn.com
toast.net
```

I want to add a duplicate column and add the headers `domain` and `matches` so my `csv` will look like:

```
domain       matching
google.com   google.com
yahoo.com    yahoo.com
cnn.com      cnn.com
toast.net    toast.net
```

I tried the following in my python script using pandas:

```
df = read_csv('temp.csv')
df.columns = ['domain', 'matching']
df['matching'] = df['domain']
df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

but I am getting the following error:

> "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements".

I assume I need to add another column first?  Can I do this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter `name` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""google.com
yahoo.com
cnn.com
toast.net"""

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), names=['domain'])
#real data
#df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', names=['domain'])

print (df)
       domain
0  google.com
1   yahoo.com
2     cnn.com
3   toast.net

df['matching'] = df['domain']

print (df.to_csv(index=False))
#real data
#df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
domain,matching
google.com,google.com
yahoo.com,yahoo.com
cnn.com,cnn.com
toast.net,toast.net
```

You can modify your solution, but you lost first row, because it is read as column name:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
print (df)
#real data
#df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
  google.com
0  yahoo.com
1    cnn.com
2  toast.net

df.columns = ['domain']
df['matching'] = df['domain']

df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

But you can add parameter `header=None` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and remove second value from `df.columns = ['domain', 'matching']`, because first `DataFrame` has only one column:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""google.com
yahoo.com
cnn.com
toast.net"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None)
print (df)
#real data
#df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', header=None)
            0
0  google.com
1   yahoo.com
2     cnn.com
3   toast.net

df.columns = ['domain']
df['matching'] = df['domain']

df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You need only change `io.StringIO(temp)` to `'temp.csv'` , then it will be works nice.

Comment: The issue I'm having with this is that it wants a unicode input, which you specified with temp=u""... but I'm taking a csv as input, so when I do: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('temp.csv'), header=None), I get the error, "TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str"